# Missing file after adding multiple files to the tablespace in Oracle

Tags: oracle, rman

I ran a series of 100 commands in SQL Developer:

```
alter tablespace RRODTBL add datafile '/oradb/PRODDB/data4/prodtbl_171.dbf' size 10M autoextend on next 128M  maxsize 31G;
alter tablespace RRODTBL add datafile '/oradb/PRODDB/data4/prodtbl_172.dbf' size 10M autoextend on next 128M  maxsize 31G;
alter tablespace RRODTBL add datafile '/oradb/PRODDB/data4/prodtbl_173.dbf' size 10M autoextend on next 128M  maxsize 31G;
[...]
```

And then it turned out that the files look like this:

```
/oradb/PRODDB/dbs/MISSING00171      RECOVER
/oradb/PRODDB/dbs/MISSING00172      RECOVER
/oradb/PRODDB/dbs/MISSING00173      RECOVER
[...]
```

I deleted this tablespace, but I have a question: What could be the cause of these files?

Did I create them too quickly in SQL Developer?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the alert log? The MISSING001 entries typically mean that [the data files don't have an entry in the control file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/osrecvry.htm#CHDIBHDI), but I'm not sure how that would have happened in your case.

Comment: The first thing I would confirm is that the path `/oradb/PRODDB/data4` exists, that the partition has free space, and that the oracle user has permissions to write files there.

Comment: The path was correct and there was a lot of space in the filesystem.
I think you shouldn't add 100 files at the same time.

In my opinion, the database put information in the controlfile, but the operating system did not manage to create the files.